# to print amstrong no from 100 to 10000 in c

Tags: c

code dosen't throw any error but dosen't give desired output
using ubuntu for execution 
but output dosen't show a single value
output shown is as follows
Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are
v
v
v

```
/* Print Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    int orignal,rem,no,result=0,n=0,i;
    printf("Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are\nv\nv\nv\n");
    for(i=100;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            orignal/=10;
            ++n;
        }
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            rem=orignal%10;
            result+=pow(rem,n);
            orignal/=10;
        }
        if(result==i)
            printf("%d\n",i);
        result=0;
        n=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` is not reset, is one thing. `int` might be too small, `pow` is vulnerable too. Time for you to get your debugger out.

Comment: Same for `n`, it's not being reset at the end of the loop. Still not the real problem since `371` is a Armstrong number and it's not being output. Try debug line by line and see where it fails and why `if(result==i)` is not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not resetting the value of n and result. Both were summing up for each iteration, thus providing wrong output. Also, check for the range.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    int orignal,rem,no,result=0,n=0,i;
    printf("Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are\n");
    for(i=100;i<=1000;i++) //153 is a armstrong number!
    {
        result=0, n=0; //have to reset for each number
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            orignal/=10;
            ++n;
        }
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            rem=orignal%10;
            result+=pow(rem,n);
            orignal/=10;
        }
        if(result==i)
            printf("%d\n",i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to run your code and I got this output:

```
Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are
v
v
v
371
```

So `371` is being output. The problem is that variable `n` and `result` must be resetted at the end of the loop, so you have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    int orignal,rem,no,result=0,n=0,i;
    printf("Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are\nv\nv\nv\n");
    for(i=371;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            orignal/=10;
            ++n;
        }
        orignal=i;
        while(orignal!=0)
        {
            rem=orignal%10;
            result+=pow(rem,n);
            orignal/=10;
        }
        if(result==i)
            printf("%d\n",i);

        n=0;
        result = 0;
    }
}
```

And the final output, which is also the correct one is:

```
Amstrong no from 100 to 10000 are
v
v
v
371
407
```